# Nearest RGB value query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, sqlite

So I have an application that works with colors, and I need to find the nearest neighbor in my database to any given color.

**My Question:** What SQL would I use to find the row nearest to the color I am searching for?

The below sample assumes I am searching for the color nearest to: #12AB34 (which would be 00FF00)

```
          Sample Database:
/----------------------------------\
| id | string | red | green | blue |
|====|========|=====|=======|======|
| 0  | FF0000 | 255 | 0     | 0    |
| 1  | 00FF00 | 0   | 255   | 0    |
| 2  | 0000FF | 0   | 0     | 255  |
| 3  | 000000 | 0   | 0     | 0    |
| 4  | FFFFFF | 255 | 255   | 255  |
\----------------------------------/

        Desired SQL Result:
/----------------------------------\
| id | string | red | green | blue |
|====|========|=====|=======|======|
| 1  | 00FF00 | 0   | 255   | 0    |
\----------------------------------/
```

### NOTE:

Both the database and the color I am searching for can be searched with Hex, RGB, HSL, HSV, and CMYK values.

Comment: this isn't easy. you can't just compare rgb values for "nearness", because what looks "near" in rgb numbers can be completely "distant" in practice. you need to compare hsv values only, which matches more what the human eye will consider "near".

Comment: There is some truth to this but actually, HSL and HSV also have this problem. You need to convert it to a spectrum such as YIQ to deal with it.

Comment: @Dekel Checking that question... I will close if it answers my question.